# Error with get method of double hashing hash table

Tags: java, hash, double-hashing

I have the method below for getting the value of a key entered in a double hashing class. It keeps saying there's an error after it runs.

```
 /* Function to get value of a key */
 public int get(String key) 
 {
    int hash1 = myhash1( key );
    int hash2 = myhash2( key );

    while (table[hash1] != null && !table[hash1].key.equals(key))
    {
        hash1 += hash2;
        hash1 %= TABLE_SIZE;
    }
    return table[hash1].value;
}
```

first I have to insert a new name and value into the hash table which works fine if after that I have example:

```
    System.out.println( "Please enter the name of the person you want to search for: " );
    System.out.println( "Value= " + ht.get(scan.next()));
```

but if I have :

```
    System.out.println( "Please enter the name of the person you want to search for: " );
    System.out.println( "Value= " + ht.get(scan.nextLine()));
```

it says that theres an error. which means it the method doesn't accept a whole line of string which includes space, etc but it only accepts a single string. Netbeans says the error is with this line:

```
return table[hash1].value;
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what does it say? NullPointerException? That would mean that table[hash1] is null. If it's an IndexOutOfBounds then that would mean hash1 is calculated wrong. We need more information here

Comment: @EdgarBoda the compiler doesn't tell me, it just says "at HashTable.get(HashTable.java:73)"

Comment: @EdgarBoda I tried again with dr java and it says nullpointerexception

Comment: ok I would say your problem is that `table[hash1]` is null. As you access `table[hash1]` in the head of your while loop, the index should be alright. So you should check why `table[hash1]` is null.

Comment: pleas post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of your program.

Comment: That is not a compiler error.  Its a runtime error. It means you are trying to use a value which hasn't been initialised.  Using a debugger is often the best way to debug your program. It is usually the button next to Run. ;)

Answer (score 0):

One of the conditions for exiting the loop is

```
while (table[hash1] != null
```

This means you know table[hash1] could be `null` but you then do

```
return table[hash1].value;
```

And you get a NullPointerException.  This would be obvious with a debugger.

I suggest you check the table[hash1] before attempting to use it like

```
return table[hash1] == null ? null : table[hash1].value;
```

A better way to write this method is

```
// don't go around forever if the hash2 is poor.
for(int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
    Entry e = table[hash1];
    if (e == null) return null;
    if (e.key.equals(key)) return e.value;
    hash1 += hash2;
    hash1 %= TABLE_SIZE;
}
// should never happen if hash2 is well chosen.
return null;
```